How to echo current variable value with statement on same line as set statement when in Windows command prompt?
In batch scripting I can do something like
echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a jjj = 0

echo Want _1:  &  set /a jjj+=1  &  echo _%jjj%
REM batch output    _0          bad
REM CLI output      _0          bad
echo Checking:  jjj is %jjj%

echo Want _2:  &  set /a jjj+=1  &  echo _!jjj!
REM batch output    _2          good
REM CLI output      _!jjj!      bad
echo Checking:  jjj is %jjj%

echo Want _3:  &  set /a jjj+=1  &  call echo _%jjj%
REM batch output    _2          bad
REM CLI output      _2          bad
echo Checking:  jjj is %jjj%

echo Want _4:  &  set /a jjj+=1  &  call echo _!jjj!
REM batch output    _4          good
REM CLI output      _!jjj!      bad
echo Checking:  jjj is %jjj%

echo Want _5:  &  set /a jjj+=1  &  call echo _%%jjj%%
REM batch output    _5          good
REM CLI output      _%4%        bad
echo Checking:  jjj is %jjj%

echo Want _6:  &  set /a jjj+=1  &  call echo _!!jjj!!
REM batch output    _6          good
REM CLI output      _!!jjj!!    bad
echo Checking:  jjj is %jjj%

endlocal

The echo Checking:  jjj is %jjj% statements produce the correct output in every instance (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6) when run as a batch file, and also when run at the command prompt.
Now notice the set and echo commands paired together on the same line in each case.  These are the problem.
Having set and echo on a single line within the batch file seems to mean that they are treated like a block arising within a for loop or an if statement, so for a batch file this can be handled with either delayed expansion (using ! instead of %) or an explicit call statement (see ss64 and Reddit)  ... or even both of those together (albeit redundantly).
However, when run directly in the command prompt (CLI) under Windows 10, I cannot find any way to access the most recent value of the variable if the set and echo are on the same line, separated by an ampersand (&).
Is there a way to do this, or is it a known limitation?

Can you please clarify whether you are enabling delayed variable expansion at the beginning of your manual cmd.exe session, (like you are in your batch file)?

Try: echo Want _5:  &  set /a jjj+=1  &  call echo _^%jjj^% This works OK in the CLI

@Compo :   yes ...or, trying to.  Literally running the same code (as above) verbatim in each environment.

Thanks, @Aacini:  I confirm that your suggestion works.  And in initial testing just now set /a jjj+=1  &  call echo _^!jjj^! and set /a jjj+=1  &  echo _^!jjj^! both also worked in the original command prompt instance.  But the variants with exclamation marks don't work in a new command prompt instance.  (Whilst set /a jjj+=1  &  echo _^%jjj^% doesn't work in any instance.)  I cannot figure out how the original CLI instance was different.  Possibly some command I ran during troubleshooting way back in the stack, which I can no longer see.  (No difference if run as admin.)

Solution 1
On the CLI, the setlocal command has no effect, but you can enable delayed expansion by using cmd /V:ON
echo Want _7:  &  set /a jjj+=1 > NUL &  cmd /v:on /c echo _!jjj!

The cmd /v:on creates a new cmd.exe instance, therefore it can't modify variables of the parent process. It's a bit like the setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion command.
Solution 2
Mentioned by Aacini in his comment:
You can still use CALL, but you have to add some carets in the variable name, because you cannot escape a percent sign on the CLI.
Even the carets don't escape anything, but they create an undefined variable name which is not expanded.
echo Want _8:  &  set /a jjj+=1 > NUL &  call echo %^jj^j%

Solution 3
Use the set /a output itself.
On the CLI, set /a always outputs the result without newline, to avoid this use redirect to >NUL.
echo Want _9:  &  set /a jjj+=1 > NUL &  set /a jjj & echo:

Solution 4
set /a var+=1 > NUL & for /F "tokens=1-31" %%= in ("-") do @call echo var is %%=var%%= 

This is an absolutely safe variant and cannot be broken by any crafted variable.
It creates 31 for-meta-variables, the first is %%, but the 25th is %= and contains nothing.
The trick is how %%=VAR%%= expands.
In the first percent expansion phase %%= just stays as it.
In the FOR meta variable expansion phase the %= expands to nothing, after this phase the line looks like var is %var%.
In the end the CALL can expand the %var% without problems.
And because every percent sign is followed by an equal sign, and because variable names can't start with an equal sign, it's safe.

A very inefficient fourth solution would be: set /A jjj+=1 >NUL & for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %i in ('set jjj') do @echo %i It has additionally the disadvantage that by chance the value of another environment variable also beginning with jjj could be additionally output. Solution 3 is definitely the best to output the integer value of an environment variable.

Thanks for the explanations.  I confirm that all three solutions work correctly in both my original CLI instance and a new instance.  As a slight adaptation of your Solution 3, for debugging set /a jjj+=1 > NUL &  set jjj (without /a) also works, although the output of either version of Solution 3 can't be used as part of a string.  However, Solutions 1 and 2 can be, as in set /a jjj+=1 &  set /a aaa+=1 & call echo _%^jj^j%_%^aa^a% (one echo statement produces a string containing values for two distinct variables).

@Mofi, thanks for the additional idea.  I confirm it works, subject to the limitation you mentioned.  BTW, you also are correct to note that Solution 3 only applies to integer values.

For Solution 1, I notice that it is possible to call cmd /v:on once only, at the beginning, and thereafter simply set /a jjj+=1 > NUL &  echo _!jjj! etc..   When I tried this, my command prompt window remained open, but the list of previous commands was no longer available through the arrow keys (although still visible by scrolling upward).

For Solution 2, it's a good insight that the carets are not needed specifically to escape %.  From what you said, it seems that when parsing the CALL statement (prior to evaluating set) the interpreter looks for a variable name with carets in it;  when it cannot find such a name, it cannot substitute a value, so it retains the encoding with carets, which is passed on to the ECHO statement, which is able to deal with the carets (ignore them, or rather, then the carets are escape characters, but with nil effect).  So ^%^j^j^j^% and %j^jj% work, but %j^^jj% and ^%jjj% don't.

This means that Solution 2 has a theoretical limitation too.  Running, say, set /a jjj+=1 &  call echo _%j^jj% will usually have the desired effect (output of matching numbers, such as 133_133), but not if the interpreter parsing CALL can actually find a variable name containing a caret in the specified place.  Thus, if we run set j^^jj=thwarted prior to the above command, then the output will become something like 134_thwarted.  I personally wouldn't intentionally create variable names containing carets, but it is technically possible.

It appears that Solution 3 will also fail if previously cmd /q (quiet) was run.

Solution 1 seems able to work without limitation at the command line.  Would there be any problem with using cmd /v:on in a batch file instead of setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion?  (Cf. documentation for set.)

Thanks, @jeb.  I confirm that your Solution 4 works for me, although — even with the remarks you included — the complete details of how it works are not obvious to me.  So then there is a trade-off in choosing between code that can handle every (theoretical) circumstance but is a bit harder to understand, versus code that's perhaps easier to understand but fails in a few rare/theoretical circumstances.  These are not criticisms, just observations, and with four or five solutions to choose from, there should now be something for everyone  :-)

@DIV I add some more explanations to solution 4, hope it helps

Thanks, I think I've got it now.
set /a var+=1 > NUL & for /F "tokens=1-31" %%= in ("1 DURIAN 3 4 CANTALOUPE 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 BANANA 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 APPLE 26 27 28 29 30") do @call echo var is %%=var%%= using token 25, whilst token 15 is %3, token 5 is %), and token 2 is %^&. Token 31 is %Cempty%C.  Token 32 is %Dnot defined%D.
produces
var is %APPLEvar%APPLE using token 25, whilst token 15 is BANANA, token 5 is CANTALOUPE, and token 2 is DURIAN. Token 31 is empty.  Token 32 is %Dnot defined%D.  (I couldn't figure out the syntax to access %%, the first token.)

Besides starting at %%, we can alternatively start at %&, with the same alignment as before ...
set /a var+=1 > NUL & for /F "tokens=2-25" %^&= in ("1 DURIAN 3 4 CANTALOUPE 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 BANANA 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24") do @call echo var is %%=var%%= using token 25
produces
var is 84 using token 25
... or with a shifted alignment
set /a var+=1 > NUL & for /F "tokens=1-25" %^&= in ("1 DURIAN 3 4 CANTALOUPE 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 BANANA 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23") do @call echo var is %%=var%%= using token 24 (not 25)
produces
var is 87 using token 24 (not 25).

As the %= in your Solution 4 is token 25, which will be empty provided that the quoted string has fewer than 25 elements, we could (optionally) slightly reduce the number of for-meta-variables to tokens=1-25.
BTW (off-topic), it seems specifying more than 31 tokens, such as tokens=1-32, is invalid, although I cannot find that documented.

@DIV, We should not start with any other than %%= , because every other meta-variable can fail by a crafted variable. In your example try this line before set "^&= in ("1 DURIAN 3 4 CANTALOUPE 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 BANANA 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24") do @call echo var is =%1 in ("d d") do echo HACK ---"
